# get month from date meta query in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I store a date type stored by ACF Pro in custom meta "event_date" and I want to filter event by months with a query. The data is stored in

I know that I need to use meta_query array like this :

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'value' => ?,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
);
```

But the `meta query` allows to compare with a full date. How to compare if the month variable (number 1 to 12) is the same that the `event_date` meta month ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of the data?

Comment: My data is stored as date format I thinik. I use ACF Pro plugin to store it

Comment: What is the 'Save format' of your date field? You can see this probably below 'Required?' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ACF's default date 'save format' which is 'yymmdd'. Try the following 'meta query'.

**FOR MONTH:**

```
$month = date('m'); // Change to static if not current month (should be 2 digits)
$start_date = date('Y'.$month.'01'); // First day of the month
$end_date = date('Y'.$month.'t'); // Last day of the month

$args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
);
```

**FOR YEAR:**

```
$year = date('Y'); // Change to static if not current year (should be 4 digits)
$start_date = date($year.'0101'); // First day of the year
$end_date = date($year.'1231'); // Last day of the year

$args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
);
```

> NOTE: Instead of `'type' => 'DATE'`, you can use `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` too.

Comment: Great one ! I didn't think to do it like that ! Thanks !
I tried the same think for year but it doesn't work, do you know why ?